# AutoSize Layout problems on new devices after update Xcode / Xamarin

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, xcode8, xcode7

I am currently trying to update an iOS app, that has been published 15 months ago.
We have been rejected from Apple because of Xam.Plugin.Connectivity not being up to date.
We updated Connectivity, and so we had to update the iOS SDK to 11 and change compilation settings !

We succeed to be validated by Apple after all that, but a bigger problem came...

After tests on Ipad 12" and iPhone 6S (bigger screen), the usable visual area of the app didn't auto size layout at all (see the file attached) ...

On smaller screen, we do not have this issue.

The previous versions of the app do not have this auto size issue, and the usable area is the size of a smaller iPad .

[image]

I wonder if someone know from where this problem could come, and more important, how to solve it !

You would have all my gratitude :) !

(I am also trying to use XCode 7 and not XCode 9, but i cant download the XCode 7 files on developer.apple.com/downloads ( 403 error)

Thanks you very very very much.

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout ? Attach the code how you place these controls.

Comment: The previously published app with XCode 7 work nice on big screen.But once we updated to XCode 8 and further.... the app is only well sized with iphone 5 and ipad 9,3"